# Install Arduino IDE in Raspberry Pi 3 model B

Tags: arduino-uno, usb, raspberrypi

I am trying to install Arduino IDE in my Raspberry Pi model 3 but it is unable to locate file path.

I use the following steps

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install arduino
```

and in result I found this

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install arduino 
Hit:1 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian stretch InRelease                 
Ign:2 http://repository.pi4j.com wheezy InRelease                
Hit:3 http://repository.pi4j.com wheezy Release    
Reading package lists... Done
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package arduino
```

I am searching for a solution but not able to understand what's the problem here.

Any ideas to make it work will be helpful.

Comment: Have you tried grabbing the Linux ARM build directly from https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/Software and installing it? Have you tried searching for the package name? `apt-cache search arduino`

Comment: Downloading the latest version from the arduino.cc is much better idea. If there is Arduino IDE available in the repository, it's usually super obsolete. For example version in Ubuntu repositories is 1.0.5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Visit https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/Software in your browser, and click the Linux ARM link under ‘Download the IDE’.

```
cd Downloads/
tar -xf arduino-1.8.3-linuxarm.tar.xz
```

Extract the file to your /opt directory, then open a Terminal and run the install.sh script to install.

```
sudo mv arduino-1.8.3 /opt
sudo /opt/arduino-1.8.3/install.sh
```

You will find Arduino IDE under Menu > Programming. Open the app to start programming your Arduino board.

Hope this helps.

Comment: worked for me! In the Arduino website you'll find two versions (32-bits and 64-bits). In my case (and it seems in the case of this example) the 32-bits worked fine. I'm using a Raspberry Pi 3B with an Arm v7.